# Pick Multiple Photos or Albums from Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

I made this code:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);
```

This code only let me choose one picture from gallery. I want to know how I can choose multiple photos or albums. I don't want to make my own gallery, I want to use the default gallery from smartphone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in standard way from API 18, with next code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECTED_PICTURE);
```

More details about [`Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

**Update**: processing of result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECTED_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
            Uri dataUri = data.getData();
            if (null != dataUri) {
                processDataUri(dataUri);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                if (null == clipData) return;
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    Uri clipDataUri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    processDataUri(clipDataUri);
                }
                processClipData(data.getClipData());
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}

private void processDataUri(Uri uri) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        // read/copy/etc.
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != inputStream) try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: provided code will work at earlier versions, but without multi select

Comment: @tomss I guess, it won't be possible to do in standard way, you can try to find some 3rd library or implement your own picker

Comment: If I use your code how can I create a toast message that shows all names of the photos picked? Thanks.